Firebase Security Rule on service account
I'm running into a strange error:
I was writing the firestore rules for my database and I realized that my BE (in node, deployed on Google's cloud run) stopped working due to access denied problems. This seems very strange to me, from all my assessments the login from BE and therefore with SDK users should not validate these rules. Also by setting the rules completely open, the API start again working. At this point I fear that the problem is how I set up the authentication for the server-side service account... so I ask you for your point of view
firebase config
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
import stripe from "stripe";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
// Firebase configuration object containing API keys and other credentials
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY, // API key for accessing Firebase services
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN, // Domain for authentication
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID, // ID of the Firebase project
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET, // Storage bucket for Firebase storage
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID, // Sender ID for Firebase Cloud Messaging
  appId: process.env.APP_ID, // ID of the Firebase application
};
// Initialize Firebase app with the provided configuration
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Get the authentication instance from the Firebase app
export const auth = getAuth(app);
// Get the Firestore database instance from the Firebase app
export const db = getFirestore(app);

// Initialize Stripe with the private key from the environment variables
export const STRIPE = new stripe(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);

service account
import admin from "firebase-admin";
// Defining service account configuration object using environment variables
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT = {
  type: process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
  project_id: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  private_key_id: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
  private_key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"), // Replacing escaped newline characters
  client_email: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
  client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  auth_uri: process.env.AUTH_URI,
  token_uri: process.env.TOKEN_URI,
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: process.env.AUTH_PROVIDER,
  client_x509_cert_url: process.env.CLIENT_CERT_URL,
  universe_domain: process.env.UNIVERSE_DOMAIN,
};

// Initializing Firebase Admin SDK with service account credentials
export default admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(SERVICE_ACCOUNT),
  serviceAccountId: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
});

One example API
import {
    or,
    and,
    doc,
    query,
    where,
    getDoc,
    getDocs,
    deleteDoc,
    updateDoc,
    collection,
  } from "firebase/firestore/lite";
  import {
    generateToken,
    createResponse,
    createCustomToken,
    sendErrorResponse,
    returnErrorResponse,
    decryptPasswordFunction,
  } from "../../utils/utils.js";
  import {
    SUCCESS,
    EVENT_EXPIRED,
    OTP_INCORRECT,
    LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
    USER_NOT_FOUND,
    NOT_AUTHORISED,
    OTP_TIME_EXPIRED,
    EVENT_NOT_EXISTS,
    EVENT_NOT_ACTIVE,
    PASSWORD_MISMATCH,
    UNAUTHENTICATED_USER,
    EMAIL_OR_PHONE_NUMBER_REQUIRED,
    NOT_REGISTER_WITH_EMAIL_PASSWORD,
    USER_NOT_ACTIVE,
  } from "../../constants/responseConstants.js";
  import {
    SUCCESS_CODE,
    VALIDATION_ERROR_CODE,
    BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_CODE,
  } from "../../constants/statusConstants.js";
  import moment from "moment";
  import admin from "../../constants/serviceAccount.js";
  import { db } from "../../constants/fireBaseConfig.js";
  import { JWT, USER_ROLE, COLLECTION } from "../../constants/constant.js";
  import { loginValidator, languageValidator } from "../../shared/validator.js";
  
  //Login function appears to handle user authentication
  export const login = async (request, response) => {
    console.info("Starting execution of the login function ", request);
    // Define Firestore collections
    const USERS = collection(db, COLLECTION.USER);
    const OTPS = collection(db, COLLECTION.OTP);
    const EVENTS = collection(db, COLLECTION.EVENT);
    const APP_INFOS = collection(db, COLLECTION.AAP_INFO);
    try {
      const { body } = request;
      // Validate request language
      let languageValue = languageValidator().validate(request.query);
      const { respose_language } = languageValue.value;
      // Validate request body data
      const VALIDATE_DATA = loginValidator().validate(body);
      const { error, value } = VALIDATE_DATA;
      // Return validation error response if validation fails
      if (error)
        return await sendErrorResponse(
          response,
          VALIDATION_ERROR_CODE,
          error.details[0].message,
          respose_language
        );
      // Destructure validated values
      const { password, phone_number, otp, email } = value;
      // Check for required fields
      if (
        (body?.email && body?.phone_number) ||
        (!body?.email && !body?.phone_number)
      )
        return await sendErrorResponse(
          response,
          BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_CODE,
          EMAIL_OR_PHONE_NUMBER_REQUIRED,
          respose_language
        );
      let userQuery, userSnapShot,eventData;
      // Handle email case
      if (email) {
        userQuery = query(USERS, where("email", "==", email));
        userSnapShot = await getDocs(userQuery);
      }

Error
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.11.1_lite): RestConnection RPC 'RunQuery' 0x88991bb1 failed with error:  [FirebaseError: Request failed with error: Missing or insufficient permissions.] {
  code: 'permission-denied',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
} url:  https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/app-power-bank/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery request: {
  structuredQuery: {
    from: [ { collectionId: 'users' } ],
    where: {
      fieldFilter: {
        field: { fieldPath: 'email' },
        op: 'EQUAL',
        value: { stringValue: 'admin-9482@yopmail.com' }
      }
    },
    orderBy: [ { field: { fieldPath: '__name__' }, direction: 'ASCENDING' } ]
  }
}
Error occured in login function:  [FirebaseError: Request failed with error: Missing or insufficient permissions.] {
  code: 'permission-denied',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
}

Give me your point of view..

You show a lot of code initializing the Admin SDK, but none of the queries here actually use it. The error message is even telling you that the error is coming from "@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.11.1_lite)", which means it is going to be subject to security rules.  What exactly is it that doesn't work the way you expect here?  Please edit the question to be clear.

What I would like is to bypass the firestore security rules, since I am on the server...this is my problem....

From my read, there is a fair amount of confusion in your post.  You are showing use of both the Firebase Client SDK (and the "lite" version of Firestore), as well as use of the Firebase Admin SDK.
For the use of the Client SDK, you aren't showing how that library is authenticating.  You are showing use of a Service Account with the Admin SDK, but that is not the same connection to Firebase as is the Client SDK.
I have seen this confusion a lot before.  Recognize that the Admin SDK (which uses a Service Account) runs in "privileged mode" (or "root mode" or "god mode") and is not associated to a user account within your Firebase Authentication service.  Use of the Admin SDK (or more specifically of "privileged mode") bypassed all Firebase Security Rules.
But the Client SDK is intended to be used by "end users".  Its use is intended for users that will authenticate against Firebase Authentication, and requests via the Client SDK invoke the Firebase Security Rules.
Your code snippets above do not indicate how the (Firebase Client SDK) code is authenticating.
If fear that you have confused Admin & Client SDKs, and how they work / how they behave with respect to authentication and Security Rules.

I understand what you mean. Thank you.
I think at this point that the problem is how do I access the DB,I'm afraid I'm not using the sdk server for this... can I ask you how you would set up the code to make the queries from admin skd work?

I think you want to take a step back for a second and ask yourself (or tell us :) ) what it is you are trying to accomplish functionally (not the coding implementation).  If this is a client app (web, mobile, desktop, whatever), then I would suggest you consider having the client app use the Client SDK to query the database directly.  No need to use "middleware" with Firebase except for specific use cases.  This is a fundamental different model when using other backends -- especially different databases such as MongoDB or one of the SQL thingies.
